# Call button from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I need help to modify this script. I want when I click on a table row to call the button below using the unique id of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(selector).click(); //selector = h:commandLink
});


$(selector).find('tr').each(function(){ //selector = h:dataTable
        $(this).click(function(){
                $(selector).trigger('click'); //selector = h:commandLink       
        });
});

<h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" action="#{bean.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none">

</h:commandLink>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem, please?

P.S
This is the code of the table:

```
<h:form id="form" >
<!-- The sortable data table -->
<h:dataTable id="dataTable" headerClass="columnHeader" value="#{bean.dataList}" binding="#{table}" var="item">
    <!-- Check box -->
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox style="margin-left: 0px;" value="#{bean.value}" class="checkall" >
                <f:ajax listener="#{bean.value}" render="@form" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </f:facet>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this);" value="#{bean.value" >
            <!-- if the user deselects one row deselect the main checkbox -->
            <f:ajax listener="#{bean.deselectMain}" render="@form" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        <!-- Click on table code -->
        <h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" action="#{bean.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none">

        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>
    <!-- Row number -->
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="№" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" />
    </h:column>
..........

</h:dataTable>
```

This is part of the code generated into the web browser:

```
<tr class="">
<td>
<input id="form:dataTable:1:j_idt17" type="checkbox" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'highlight(this);','mojarra.ab(this,event,\'valueChange\',0,\'@form\')')" name="form:dataTable:1:j_idt17">
<a id="form:dataTable:1:lnkHidden" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('form'),{'form:dataTable:1:lnkHidden':'form:dataTable:1:lnkHidden'},'');return false" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none" href="#"></a>
</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>35435</td>
```

Comment: If you could be more complete, it would help.  Toss up a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: If Ian has answered your question, mark his as the chosen answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your use of JSP (or whatever language), the `id` attributes are what you want to use to target elements, but it's a little tricky since it generates them in a complex way.

Since you need to handle clicking on table rows, you could bind the event and trigger the `click` event like this:

```
$('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
    $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
});
```

This is required to be inside of the `$(document).ready` handler as well.

This will bind one `click` event handler to the `<table>`. When a `<tr>` is clicked, this handler runs, and `this` refers to the specific row. With that, I find the `<a>` (linkButton) contained in that row, with the specific `id` you're targeting, and trigger its `click` event.

The way I find the linkButton is with the "attribute" (`[name]`) and "ends with" (`$=`) selector. All of the generated elements have an `id` that ends with the original `id` set (with more information, used internally, at the beginning of the `id`)...it's just how the engine generates them.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do in your `document.ready` handler, but if need to trigger the `click` event for all commandLinks that we're targeting, you could use:

```
$('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
```

So the final code I'd use is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
        $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
    }).on("click", 'a[id$="lnkHidden"]', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not working properly. When I click on the table row nothing happens.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Sorry, I didn't realize that was also a problem. Please provide more of your HTML, otherwise you can read my update to my answer which assumes things

Comment: @PeterPenzov Just updated my answer again. I think this is what you were going for. Let me know if it works/helps

Comment: I don't why but something is completely wrong maybe in my code. It's not working.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Are all your event handlers inside of `$(document).ready(function () {});`? Including the new table/row handler I provided?

Comment: No, would you edit your answer again with the complete code, please?

Comment: Now I works immediately when I load the parent page without clicking anywhere. Any idea why is that?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Because of the first line in the handler. In your original code, for some reason, you triggered the click immediately. I kept it in, but I didn't think it was necessary. I added a comment in the JS. Take that out then

Comment: Now it works but I get this error in Firebug: `too much recursion
[Break On This Error]  

...,c=l.length;c--;)(f=l[c])&&(v[d[c]]=!(y[d[c]]=f));if(i){if(o||e){if(o){for(l=[],...`

Comment: Just a guess here, but you might be catching the bubble from the button.  Here's the scenario:  click on the `<tr>`, your event handler clicks on the `<h:commandLink>`, which then bubbles back up to the `<tr>`, which then clicks on the `<h:commandLink>`, and so on.  This isn't a definite answer to your recursion, just a possibility.

Comment: @Travis That's definitely a great point, and I would expect that to be the problem. Can't believe I didn't realize/see it either. Thanks for at least pointing it out :)

Comment: @PeterPenzov I just updated my answer's code again, per Travis' suggestion. Hopefully that fixes it now.

Comment: @PeterPenzov So sorry it took so many tries. Just a little confusion and wrongdoings on my part. Glad it works now though :)

Comment: I noticed a problem. After I make a AJAX call the JavaScript is not working. I described the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910794/not-to-open-a-new-page-when-table-check-box-is-clicked Any I idea why after AJAX call the code is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Since events bubble up the DOM tree, if your `<tr>` is inside your `<h:commandLink>` then the click event will bubble up and fire.

If your `<h:commandLink>` is inside your `<tr>`, then your selection syntax is wrong.  When you do:

```
$(selector).find('tr')
```

This is attempting to find a descendant `<tr>` inside the `<h:commandLink>`.

**One big thing** is that your code as is is attaching event listeners on every single row in your table.  This is bad practice since JavaScript events bubble.  What you should do is something like this assuming what you want to click (`selector`) is actually inside your row:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).find(selector).click();
});
```

This will bind an event handler to all `<table>`'s to listen for clicks on `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You said `when I click on a table row` which means you need to register a click event for each rows and in this case you don't need to use `each`, instead you can use

```
$('table#dataTable').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    // here your code goes to click the button with ID lnkHidden
    $('#lnkHidden').trigger('click');

    // after the update of your question
    $(this).find('td:first a').trigger('click');
});
```