# Not to open a new page when table check box is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have this JavaScript which opens new page when I click on a table row:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "tr", function () {
        $(this).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
    }).on("click", 'a[id$="lnkHidden"]', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

The JavaScript is used to call this button:

```
<h:commandLink id="lnkHidden" action="#{bean.pageRedirect}" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; display:none">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sessionValue}" value="#{item.value}" />
    </h:commandLink>
```

The code works well but it turns out that when I select the first column of the table which is a check box I also open a new page. How I can modify the JavaScript not to open a new page when the check box is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Listen for clicks on table cells instead of rows, then ignore if the cell's in the first column.

Sticking with jQuery, this might work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table[id$="dataTable"]').find("tbody").on("click", "td", function () {
        if (this.cellIndex > 0) {
            $(this.parentNode).find('a[id$="lnkHidden"]').trigger("click");
        }
    }).on("click", 'a[id$="lnkHidden"]', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: the code works but it turns out that there is a problem. When I select the check box and I click on the row I'm not redirected to the new page. If I reload the page and I click on the table row I'm redirected. One idea why it's not working: I have a AJAX request in a background which is executed then I click on a table check box. How I can solve this?

Comment: Might need to see the generated HTML and any other JavaScript associated with the checkbox to solve that one.

Comment: This is the generated html code after the check box is selected (after the AJAX event)  http://pastebin.com/WY483xmt